# How to connect to a IPsec VPN with WireGuard client?

Tags: ipsec, wireguard

is it possible at all, because I know that you can't do this with openconnect?
I have:

- gateway ip
- preshared key
- login
- password
- empty ipsec id (group)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible -- different protocols